# How to access the text field that do not have id property in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

i am working in selenium i want access a text field and fill with any value but that field do not have any id attribute, so tell me how to locate that field.

Comment: Only way you can is find the parent and see if you can read from parent children.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of an HTML markup? It really depends on the context if there are no direct "hooks" like IDs...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cssselector or xpath.

you can find lots more on google . one useful link is -

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.html

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot add id to element, then you can use other options:

- use other attributes (e.g.name or any other you have) - it is not reliable, because attributes can change in time. Example:

  > //div[@name='some_name']
- use your HTML layout to locate element - it's even less reliable, because your HTML layout may be changed in time. Example:

  > //footer//div[position()=2]

In order to make it easy to write your custom XPath expression I would suggest to use [FireFinder for FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/uk/firefox/addon/firefinder-for-firebug/) FireFox plugin. It supports both CSS and XPath expressions and makes writing expressions really straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

For typing into a textbox there is no need to have an ID. You can do it with XPath or CSS.